# Bootstrap Input-Buttons become writable

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

So this is what my Button looks like:

```
<input class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dashboard" value="Zurück" onclick="doStuff();">
```

Just normal Bootstrap stuff. But things get weird when I press this button and change its value

https://i.imgur.com/v3VaxLM.gifv

```
$("#dashboard").val("Lehrer-Login");
```

is all I did.
How can I stop it from being writable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is not a button, it's a default input field, because you don't have set a type.

Add the type ´button` to your input field and everything should work as excepted.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dashboard" value="Zurück" onclick="doStuff();">
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add type = "button" to your input element.

eg:

```
<input type = "button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dashboard" value="Zurück" onclick="doStuff();">
```